# ftpClient wont upload,what am I missing?

Tags: java, android, ftp, ftp-client

Yeah, so I am using this code but whenever I run it, it doesnt upload anything. I have a similar code in another program the works perfect. What have I missed?

```
    public void upload(){
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                if (Looper.myLooper() == null)
                {
                    Looper.prepare();
                }
                FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
                FileInputStream inputStream = null;
                int Upload = sharedPreferences.getInt("Upload", 1);
                if (Upload == 1) {

                    try {
                        ftpClient.connect(InetAddress.getByName("XXX.net"));
                        ftpClient.login("XXX", "XXX");
                        ftpClient.changeWorkingDirectory("/public_html/Images/Cross");
                        ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE, FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
                        File file = new File(getApplicationInfo().dataDir + "/files/" + "temp" + ".jpg");
                        inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
                        ftpClient.storeFile("temporary.jpg", inputStream);
                        file.delete();
                        ftpClient.logout();
                        ftpClient.disconnect();
                    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (SocketException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

...
}
```

Comment: Aren't you deleting the file after uploading it?

Comment: You aren't getting any Exceptions?

Comment: yes and thats the point, I only want it on the ftp server
@AleksandarStefanović none